# Obtaining response from API in Android

Tags: java, android, api, response

I have a problem with obtaining the response from API connection, I used logcat(Log.wtf) testing it then found the logcat in the first class which in my ConnectAPI.java had received the data, but the logcat(Log.wtf) in the second class which in my main.java unable to obtain the response from the first class, please helping me figure it out what the wrong it is, many thanks!

first class(in ConnectAPI.java)

```
public static void A020 (final Context context, String Manual, final ZooCallback callback){
    HttpUrl url = new HttpUrl.Builder()
            .scheme(SCHEME)
            .host(HOST)
            .port(PORT)
            .addPathSegments(A020_PATH)
            .addQueryParameter("LId", PersonID.getID(context))
            .addQueryParameter("Coordinates", getGPS(context))
            .addQueryParameter("Manual", Manual)
            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .build();

    Log.d("A020 printing out the url", url.toString());

    mClient.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
            try {

 Log.wtf("A020 print out in connectapi",response.toString());

                if (response != null && response.isSuccessful()) {
                    String jsonData = response.body().string();
                    final JSONObject Jobject = new JSONObject(jsonData);
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            callback.onSuccess(Jobject);
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        callback.onFail("exception", e.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, final IOException e) {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    callback.onFail("onFailure", e.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

Second class(in main.java)

```
ConnectAPI.A020(context, Manual, new ZooCallback(){
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(JSONArray response){
            super.onSuccess(response);
            try{
                Log.wtf("A020 printing the response in mainjava", response.toString());


            }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.d("probleminA020", e.getMessage());
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("probleminA020", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void onFail(String title, String error){
            super.onFail(title, error);
            Log.d(TAG, error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Log.wtf can throw an exception. Your log tag is too long in Log.wtf too. [Check my answer for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45486270/obtaining-response-from-api-in-android/45486377#45486377)

Answer (score 2):

> What a Terrible Failure: Report a condition that should never happen. The error will always be logged at level ASSERT with the call stack. Depending on system configuration, a report may be added to the DropBoxManager and/or the process may be terminated immediately with an error dialog.

That is the documentation behind Log.wtf. When you use Log.wtf, there is a chance it throws an error. In which case it is caught by the try-catch you have. Don't use Log.wtf for debug, as this can crash your app.

Use Log.d (or Log.d or whatever you feel like) but **not under any circumstance use Log.wtf for debug**.

Replace Log.wtf with a different Log call (I recommend Log.d) and try again.

---

What is most likely happening is that Log.wtf throws an exception. This exception is then caught by the handy try-catch you have there. The code then prints out the error message instead. The reason it isn't printing is because it also throws an exception which you then aren't printing out fully, which explains why you don't know what is causing it

And for future purposes, when printing a stacktrace, use `e.printStackTrace` as it prints the entire stacktrace and not just the error message.

---

Another error you are facing is an issue related to your tag length. If oyu target API 24 or above, there is a 23 char limit:

> IllegalArgumentException is thrown if the tag.length() > 23 for Nougat (7.0) releases (API <= 23) and prior, there is no tag limit of concern after this API level.

If you don't target API 24 or above, ignore this part.

If you do target API 24 or above, you have to shorten the tag to 23 chars or less. It is generally a good idea to keep the tag short, API 24+ will crash the app if it isn't

Comment: In addition to changing the log type, **shorten the tag**. A tag that long is bound to throw an IllegalArgumentException. So basically: Use Log.d (or something else, NOT Log.wtf) and shorten the tag. TO less than 23 chars, no spaces

Comment: I shorten the tag to 12 chars and no space, the problem still exist, is there any possibility due to the mistake I made which related to the connection between two class?

Comment: Do you actually have some kind of response in the (I assume) PHP script? Add the logcat to your question (even if there is no error/stacktrace it is handy to have for debug)

Comment: You probably right, I'm checking the entire responses sending from backend, it might take some time, afterward I'll paste all the logcat here, I am grateful for your help!